# Popup for webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to add a sort of popup window to my html file. To give a good example of what exactly I'm looking for there is this website http://www.goodsearch.com/zipcar/coupons?open=3709630  when you click on one of the coupons a sort of pop up shows up
Does anyone know how would I do something like this? Would I use JavaScript?

I tried doing the following in JavaScript, but it’s not exactly what I want:

```
window.prompt('defaulttext', 'defaulttext')
```

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Google "Modal Window"

Comment: That is called a **modal box**, and there are many examples around the web on how to implement it. Google is your best friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/). Example:

```
$( "your-selector-here" ).dialog();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple Modal is a decent basic jQuery plugin, see [the website](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) for documentation and the plugin.